# UI frameworks for dealing with Hadoop data

Tags: angular, reactjs, hadoop, frontend, hadoop2

What is best ui framework I can use

to fetch , query , segment data from Hadoop DB through apis

We will be creating ui which will have dashboard 
For visualising Hadoop data in charts and query data by dragging and dropping data and many other custom complex ui.

It will be a data intensive web application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JDBC driver to query Hive or Presto from a front-end application, but it certainly **won't** be fast to present as a UI framework

Its better to know what you need to present ahead of time, then compute and store smaller result sets into HBase, for example, or Sqoop data out into Mysql or Postgres for querying. Other options include using Spark to load data to Mongo or Cassandra, which still would need an API layer to query against

If you need text search, then you would use Solr or Elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks for reply!! Will checkout the best possible solution!!